# c++ () operator problem

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've got another problem when trying to overload the () operator for array access:

```
const OctTreeNode*& operator()(const int i, const int j, const int k) const{ 
    return m_cells[k*m_resSqr+j*m_res+i];
}

OctTreeNode*& operator()(const int i, const int j, const int k){ 
    return m_cells[k*m_resSqr+j*m_res+i];       
}

vector<OctTreeNode*> m_cells;
```

I get a

```
C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'OctTreeNode *const' to 'const OctTreeNode *&'
```

what's the deal? i'm declaring it exactly as in another class. the only difference is that the other class is generic, and there i'm using T& instead of OctreeNode*&

Comment: Is there a reason for returning references to pointers instead of references to the elements?

Comment: ... or pointers to members? The idea of returning const references is that it might be much cheaper than returning full-blown copies, but if the type is integral or a pointer it does not make that much sense. (Assuming that you cannot return references into the real object, which would be a much better approach)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first operator should return const

```
const OctTreeNode * const & operator()(const int i, const int j, const int k) const{ 
        return m_cells[k*m_resSqr+j*m_res+i];
}
```

... or the const before the `*`, I never seem to remember -_-

First const tells us that we can't modify OctTreeNode, second one tells us that we can't modify the pointer to it (set it to NULL for example) while the third one tells us that the method doesn't change the object.

To be honest I'm unsure wether the first one is needed, as the only thing that we need to grant const correctness to the method, is to grant that nobody will change references to those pointers.

Comment: thx. but can you explain me why? why does then the first operator in http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html#faq-18.12 return Fred& and not Fred?

Comment: three consts in one expression make me confused about what those consts actually mean

Comment: @genesys, the function is `const` so it means that the reference you return can't be modified. The `const` adter the `*` means the pointer itself can't change, which is required for constness. The first `const` means the `OctTreeNode` itself can't change. This `const` isn't actually required, but for semantic `const`ness is recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Kornel is correct.  To clarify should the const be before or after the *, after. The two types `const OctTreeNode * const &` and `OctTreeNode const * const &` are identical, both are easily understood when read from right to left.

`const OctTreeNode * const &` is a reference to a const point to an OctTreeNode that is const.

`OctTreeNode const * const &` is a reference to a const pointer to a const OctTreeNode.

Note that these types are different from the invalid type `const OctTreeNode const * &`. This would be a reference to a pointer to a const OctTreeNode that is const.

Notice the last part of the sentence *a const OctTreeNode that is const*.  One of the const is redundant, and this type, had it been legal, would be equivalent to `const const OctTreeNode * &`

Answer (score 0):

There is very little point in passing by const value, as you're doing with i, j, k.

Comment: Try to tell such things in comments as this isn't an answer to the real problem.

Comment: Sorry, haven't really got the hang of this place yet :)

Comment: I sometimes pass my value parameters as const.  This helps me for two reasons - If I mistakenly try and mutate one, the compiler will inform me and secondly the semantics are now clearer.  The only drawback is function is visually larger and cognitively will likely take longer to understand.

Comment: @Stephen: As that const does not change the function other than for the compiler to check internally, you will find people suggesting using non-const signature in the header declaration (`void f( int );`) while const signature in the implementation ( `void f( const int ) {...}`). This will provide a clean API (your users don't really care whether you change or not internally the copied argument, while allowing the compiler to detect the type of mistakes you talk about. And changing that into a non-const argument (if you want to change the argument internally) won't change the header.

Answer (score 0):

The constant operator is incorrect, you are returning a non-constant reference to a pointer to a constant OctTreeNode.

That is, if you declare a pointer as

```
const int *a;
```

`a` is not constant, what `a` **points to** is constant. So when you declare the return type as

```
const OctTreeNode*&
```

the OctTreeNode is constant, but the pointer is not. This is an error because your member function is const, so the std::vector is const, and so the pointer that it returns is also constant - ultimately you try to return a const-pointer as a non-const pointer.

To correct this just remove the reference

```
const OctTreeNode* operator()
```

because there's not much point returning a reference to a constant pointer, you can't modify the pointer and the reference will (probably) have the same size as the pointer anyway.

Comment: "there's not much point returning a reference to a constant pointer" Consistency of interface? If he returns a pointer in one case and a reference-to-pointer in the other, then one version returns an lvalue and the other an rvalue. This affects whether you can do `&this->operator()(1,2,3)`, and compare the resulting pointer to another similar pointer. No idea whether that's likely to be useful to the questioner, but it is a difference between the two.

Comment: That's true, but off the top of my head I can't think of anywhere it would be useful - if you need to take the address of it you're probably going to want to change it.

Comment: Well, you might for some reason want to test whether two calls to operator() have accessed the same element (as opposed to just accessing elements that contain the same value). In this case `&foo(a,b,c)` == `&foo(x,y,z)` if and only if a == x && b == y & c == z. So there's another way to do it, if you pass around all three co-ordinates, instead of just a single reference.